# Unable to process binding template

Tags: c#, knockout.js

I have next issue:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APu3j.png)

and have next code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: $data.offers, as: 'offer'}-->
    <span data-bind="text: offer.AccommodationType"></span>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'offer-template', data: offer }"> </div>
    <!-- /ko-->
```

I don't understand why `<span data-bind="text: offer.AccommodationType"></span>` works, but `<div data-bind="template: { name: 'offer-template', data: offer }"> </div>` not works.
Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on screenshot attribute binding not at quotes.
So it should be like this: `<div class="searchresults-new-item"
         data-bind="class: CategoryCssClasses, attr:{'data-flight': AccommodationType, 'data-total-price': Offer.TotalPrice, 'data-adult-price': Offer.AdultPrice, 'data-hotel-inventory': Hotel.InventoryStatus}"></div>`

data-flight and others are in quotes.